# How to create pods with readwrite access in kubernetes with glusterfs volume

Tags: kubernetes

we have created the glusterfs endpoint and services and we have called the volumes directly on the pod creation. if I have update the files in volumes it will be directly updated /usr/share/nginx/html in the pod but I have entered  to the pod using below command

`kubectl exec -it  glusterfs-demo-pod -- /bin/bash`

and try to create a file under /usr/share/nginx/html  it was not accessible. kindly help us. i have used the below yaml code

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: XXX.XX.XX.XX
  ports:
  - port: 49152
EOF


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -                                                    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 49152
EOF


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: glusterfs
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      name: glusterfsvol
  volumes:
  - name: glusterfsvol
    glusterfs:
      endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
      path: myvol1
      readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked at me: **readOnly: false** (in pod's yaml)

I could create file(s) in mounted GlusterFS volume folder

The used yaml files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 192.168.100.126
  ports:
  - port: 49152
- addresses:
  - ip: 192.168.100.127
  ports:
  - port: 49152
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-cluster
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 49152
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: glusterfs
spec:
  containers:
  - name: glusterfs
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/glusterfs"
      name: glusterfsvol
  volumes:
  - name: glusterfsvol
    glusterfs:
      endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
      path: volume1
      readOnly: false
```